# expo push notification iOS APNS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am using expo push notifications to send notifications in my native app. For Android, I have to use FCM by setting it up in the Firebase console. Right now, I don't have an iOS device for testing. My question is whether I need to do some similar setup for notifications on iOS devices too or is it handled by expo itself? Because, the documentation only has the guide for setting up FCM and not APNS.